# sed to replace all line on the first match not working

Tags: sed, command-line, text-processing

Here's the file that i want to be edited

```
server {    
listen      99;
listen      200;
listen      300;
server_name xxxx;
root        xxxx;
...
```

I want to change the first line containing 'listen' to new words like ' listen_xyz 40;', here's my code:

```
sed -i -e '0,/listen/s/.*/listen_xyz 40;/' file
```

why it also replace first line (not matching with the pattern), so my file now look like this:

```
listen_xyz 40;
listen_xyz 40;
listen      200;
listen      300;
server_name xxxx;
root        xxxx;
...
```

whats wrong with my sed code, why it replace the first line even tho its not matchg my pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed -e '0,/listen/ s/listen.*/listen_xyz 40;/' file
server {    
listen_xyz 40;
listen      200;
listen      300;
server_name xxxx;
root        xxxx;
...
```

#### Explanation

`0,/listen/` is a range.  It matches all lines from the beginning of the file to the first line that matches the regex `listen`.  Thus, this matches the first **two** lines of your sample file.

`s/.*/listen_xyz 40;/` is a *substitute* command.  It is executed for any line in the range.  It replaces any line (`.*`) with `listen_xyz 40;`.  This means that it replace `server {` as well as `listen      99;`.

By changing the substitute command to `s/listen.*/listen_xyz 40;/`, we make sure that it only replaces lines that contain `listen`.